# queryset filter according to only first line - Django

Tags: python, django

Tying to filter data using **queryset.filter()** in Django. but it returns not what I expecting. can someone correct me.
single data cell looks like below.(each line separated by \n)

> 1. こちらは1行です。(0.57)\n
> 2. こちらは2行です。(0.67)\n
> 3. こちらは3行です。(0.77)\n
> 4. こちらは4行です。(0.87)\n
> 5. こちらは5行です。(0.697)

code like below

```
queryset = queryset.filter(predicted_result__regex = r"\A.*", predicted_result__contains='(0.5') |\
                   queryset.filter(predicted_result__regex = r"\A.*", predicted_result__contains='(0.6') |\
                   queryset.filter(predicted_result__regex = r"\A.*", predicted_result__contains='(0.7')
```

output:
this will be considering all 5 lines not only the first line.

target:
only get values contains in **first line between score** (inside brackets)**0.5 to 0.8.** all the other lines should omit.

expected result:

> 1. こちらは1行です。(0.57)\n

Comment: Won't they all filter true? You're not actually negating the bad values...

Comment: its' working code. but that's not what I want. I need to get only first line

Comment: Post the code for your two functions: predicted_result_contains and predicted_results_regex

Comment: These aren't django standard.

Comment: predicted_result is a field not a function

Comment: Fair. Why are you OR ing it all together? Is that what you want?

Comment: these are standards. please refer the link below

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: Yes. I want to do both filtering

Comment: From a design perspective why not save the number as a separate field? Then you can use it gt lte gte, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current query is that your 'single data cell' is currently a string. Using a regex to calculate what may or may not be expected will still return the entire string on 'True'. You should separate the 'text' from the 'float' values in order to query more efficiently.

```
class Model(model):
    descriptor = models.CharField()
    value = models.FloatField()
```

Now you can actually query the 'value' on it's own.

If you are unable to change the model for whatever reason, you need to do multiple queries and use the union/intersection/difference methods.

```
fives_queryset = queryset.filter(predicted_result__contains'(0.5')
sixes_queryset = queryset.filter(predicted_result__contains'(0.6')
sevens_queryset = queryset.filter(predicted_result__contains'(0.7')

result_queryset = union(fives_queryset, sixes_queryset, sevens_queryset)
```

Comment: <<'single data cell' is currently a string>> this is correct. but changing the model is not what I need. I cannot change the model. Isn't there any other way to do this

Comment: the code you posted doing the same thing. anyway thanks!